# Best practice with multiple for loop iterators

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to alter and reverse an array. As such, I want loop with a negative iterator (to access the initial array values) and a positive iterator (to write to the new array). Here's the code I have at this point. (For those who know some biology, this code writes the reverse complement of a DNA string.)

```
final char[] DNA = {'G','A','T','T','A','C','A'};
char[] revComp = new char[DNA.length];

int j = 0;
for (int i = DNA.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   switch (DNA[i]) {
      case 'A': DNA[i] = 'T'; break;
      case 'T': DNA[i] = 'A'; break;
      case 'C': DNA[i] = 'G'; break;
      case 'G': DNA[i] = 'C'; break;
   }
   revComp[j] = DNA[i];
   j++;
}
```

As you'll notice, I have  a normal i iterator and an extra j iterator that I just didn't know where to put. Is this the best way to approach this sort of situation (where two iterators are needed), or would it be better if I did it a bit differently?

Comment: I think you should worry more about the people who don't know biology and explain what it does and why one would need two iterators to do it.

Comment: You can write ``revComp[DNA.length - 1 - i] = DNA[i];``. In that way you don't need ``j``.

Comment: Apparently one does not need two iterators! However for those that are curious, more information about this problem can be found here: http://rosalind.info/problems/revc/
Be sure to click "click to expand" for more background on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could eliminate your "second" iterator (by which I mean loop counter) like

```
for (int i = 0; i < DNA.length; i++) {
    switch (DNA[i]) {
    case 'A':
        DNA[i] = 'T';
        break;
    case 'T':
        DNA[i] = 'A';
        break;
    case 'C':
        DNA[i] = 'G';
        break;
    case 'G':
        DNA[i] = 'C';
        break;
    }
    revComp[i] = DNA[DNA.length - i - 1];
}
```

Or like

```
for (int i = DNA.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    switch (DNA[i]) {
    case 'A':
        DNA[i] = 'T';
        break;
    case 'T':
        DNA[i] = 'A';
        break;
    case 'C':
        DNA[i] = 'G';
        break;
    case 'G':
        DNA[i] = 'C';
        break;
    }
    revComp[DNA.length - i - 1] = DNA[i];
}
```

which both produce a `DNA` of

```
[C, T, A, A, T, G, T]
```

and a `revComp`

```
[T, G, T, A, A, T, C]
```

when I checked with

```
System.out.println("revComp: " + Arrays.toString(revComp));
System.out.println("DNA: " + Arrays.toString(DNA));
```

Comment: Ah, that's easy. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the first one not guarantee that the element that you are copying has already been changed? Because you are changing DNA[i] and copying DNA[DNA.length - i - 1].